# Large email volumes

Tags: email

I have been asked to recommend a service that will be able to hand 50K plus emails a day. Has anyone got any ideas?

(should this sort of question be on serverfault.com?)

Thanks in advance.

Tom

Comment: What do you mean by "service" ? mailboxes ? smtp relay only ? antivirus ? antispam ?

Google Apps with postini can do that (40$ per year per user for 25GB mailboxes)

Comment: like Campaign Monitor, but for large volume emails. Google Apps Postini could be the one, ill check that out. thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe take a look at Rackspace Hosted Exchange, if your intressted in Exchange and don't like Google. Rackspace is a very solid way to host large Infrastructures, it's gonna cost you so...

Answer (score 1):

We use a program called Atomic Mail Sender ( http://www.amailsender.com/ ), but there's an entire suite of software on that site to do what you're looking for.

Note that it will be difficult to find another mail server that lets you send 50,000 emails out of it, except for the spam houses, who will charge you. It's possible to send directly from the desktop running the Atomic Mail program, but in order for it to work right, you should go to efforts to configure DNS such that the desktop looks like your mail server. This includes things like SPF records if you have them, reverse DNS, and so on.

Comment: thank you for the comment. I will see what they want to do. All good information

Answer (score 0):

Just use gmail?

Answer (score 0):

SmarterMail. We have it on a VM under VS 2005 R2 (about ready to upgrade to hyper-v/2008) but it runs great. Use built in CalmAV for anti-virus and a mix of RBLs (like Spamhaus and barracuda) and Declude w/ sniffer for anti-spam. It works great.
[alt text http://web9.twitpic.com/img/62454293-b526813a5021548b46ebf71f65881cce.4b698d6e-full.png](http://web9.twitpic.com/img/62454293-b526813a5021548b46ebf71f65881cce.4b698d6e-full.png)

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Safentrix](http://www.safentrix.com).